# Using a comma after the word "enclosed" in a sentence

Tags: commas

Do I need a comma after ***enclosed*** in the following sentence?

> ***Enclosed*** you will find a small token of gratitude.

Comment: I don't think that sentence is grammatically correct, in the manner of organisation not punctuation

Comment: @Leth It's a little convoluted and archaic, but the sentence is perfectly correct English in every wise, and has been a standard form of expression in this context for at least a century! (Messages once came in _envelopes_, which could actually _enclose_ the token.)

Comment: @user38660 No comma is necessary or expected. Note the several alternate wordings: _Enclosed **please find** a small token..._ or _**Please find** enclosed a small token..._

Comment: Is this something about literature ? By the way, I couldn't understand how the example you gave related the the sentence in the question.

Comment: @Leth Nothing literary here. _Enclosed please find_ and variants are standard and time-honored ways of telling a correspondent that you are enclosing something of value in an envelope or package. I don't see an "example" anywhere, though...

Comment: Either way would be OK, though in a short sentence I would say leave it out. Also you can speak the sentence with and without a pause after "Enclosed", and see which one seems more natural.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I thought "enclosed" is a participle adverb- a past participle.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a comma, and I would not recommend using one. Both *Enclosed is/are* and *attached is/are* are standard phrasing for business correspondence and also personal correspondence that mimics the business usage.

> Enclosed you will find check for tickets sent by the Chicago Dental Society.

*[Official Bulletin](https://books.google.com/books?id=kH45AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA78-IA27&dq=%22enclosed+you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJk8qG7qvOAhVQySYKHWS8AmkQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22enclosed%20you%22&f=false)*

Even though this reference is from 1921, it is still used today.

> Enclosed is our check.

*[Garner on Language and Writing](https://books.google.com/books?id=9_PdSrVNTUUC&pg=PA95&dq=%22enclosed+is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimsK--7avOAhXFwiYKHQ1fDuUQ6AEIOzAG#v=onepage&q=%22enclosed%20is%22&f=false)*

A similar sentence is

> Attached are copies of the contract.

*[GMAT Prep Course](https://books.google.com/books?id=iMXABgAAQBAJ&pg=PA498&dq=%22attached%20are%22%20email&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPwPqU7KvOAhUEKyYKHesRAVEQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22attached%20are%22%20email&f=false)*

Also

> Attached are the minutes from the last board meeting.

*[Time Management Training](https://books.google.com/books?id=EID53UV1-Z8C&pg=PA181&dq=%22attached%20are%22%20email&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPwPqU7KvOAhUEKyYKHesRAVEQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=%22attached%20are%22%20email&f=false)*

Answer (score 1):

This is an optional comma because it is a bracketing comma with weak interruption. Remember: you can omit a bracketing comma if the interruption is weak. You can tell it is a bracketing comma because you can move the “enclosed” around the sentence with no change of meaning:

> You will find, enclosed, a small token of gratitude

The interruption is weak, i.e. the sentence can easily be understood without the bracketing commas. Therefore, they can be removed.

> You will find enclosed a small token of gratitude

It follows that they can be removed even if “enclosed” is at the beginning of the sentence.

More on bracketing commas and the other three types of commas [here](http://m.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma).

Answer (score 0):

I agree, no comma is required here. However maybe the following would be a better way to say the sentence?

"Please find enclosed a small token of [our] gratitude"